# Python 3.6-Print dictionary data in readable tree structure

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I print below dictionary data in a more readable tree format like shown below using Python. This is my first time here so kindly pardon my ignorance.

```
TempDict =
{'outlook': {'sunny': {'humidity': {'high': 'no', 'normal': 'yes'}}, 'rainy': {'wind': {'strong': 'no', 'weak': 'yes'}}, 'overcast': 'yes'}}
```

Output format required -

```
outlook=sunny

    humidity=high:no
    humidity=normal:yes




outlook=rainy

    wind=strong:no
    wind=weak:yes
```

Class that is printing like this:

```
class DecisionNode:
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.children = {}

    # Visualizes the tree
    def display(self, level = 0):
        if self.children == {}:
            # reached leaf level
            print(": ", self.attribute, end="")
        else:
            for value in self.children.keys():
                prefix = "\n" + " " * level * 4
                print(prefix, self.attribute, "=", value, end="")
                self.children[value].display(level + 1)
```

Comment: It's just a bunch of print statements in a loop. What've you tried so far? Please don't assume you'll be handed over code on this website. Show your efforts

Comment: The indentation in the required format seems random to me. Is that truly what is required?

Comment: As Seth said, that indentation is pretty random. Do you really want the output like that? Why not just use `json.dumps(TempDict, indent=4)`?

Comment: or `pprint.pprint(myvar)`

Comment: class DecisionNode:
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.children = {}

    # Visualizes the tree
    def display(self, level = 0):
        if self.children == {}: # reached leaf level
            print(": ", self.attribute, end="")
        else:
            for value in self.children.keys():
                prefix = "\n" + " " * level * 4
                print(prefix, self.attribute, "=", value, end="")
                self.children[value].display(level + 1)

I have above class defined using which I need print the my output.

Comment: Also to respond about the indentation, the number of spaces is little skewed. I just need a tree structure with little less spaces but humidity in my output would need to be a newline character and right intended as shown.

Comment: @RaviK don't post code in a comment, edit your questiosn to include it and let a comment to tell us that you edited your answer

Answer (score 7):

You need to recursively run over your data!

```
temp = {'outlook': {'sunny': {'humidity': {'high': [ 'no' ,1 ] , 'normal': 'yes'}}, 'rainy': {'wind': {'strong': 'no', 'weak': 'yes'}}, 'overcast': 'yes'}}

def formatData(t,s):
    if not isinstance(t,dict) and not isinstance(t,list):
        print "\t"*s+str(t)
    else:
        for key in t:
            print "\t"*s+str(key)
            if not isinstance(t,list):
                formatData(t[key],s+1)

formatData(temp,0)
```

Output:

```
outlook
        rainy
                wind
                        strong
                                no
                        weak
                                yes
        overcast
                yes
        sunny
                humidity
                        high
                                no
                                1
                        normal
                                yes
```

You can also use `pprint`

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(myvar)
```

Sample output:

```
{'outlook': {'overcast': 'yes',
             'rainy': {'wind': {'strong': 'no', 'weak': 'yes'}},
             'sunny': {'humidity': {'high': ['no', 1], 'normal': 'yes'}}}}
```

Comment: IMO `pprint` is the best solution, I would not have known about it had I not found this thread. The name doesn't exactly make its function obvious.

Answer (score 1):

its so easy by using JSON library:

```
import json

a = {'yo': 123, 'Haha': [1,2,3]}
d = json.dumps(a, indent=4)
print(d)
```

output:

```
{
    "yo": 123,
    "Haha": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```